# Can Go executable be used as a dynamic library?

Tags: go, dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-library, .so

I am writing a generic library in GoLang and want to publish it (like a dynamic library) to be used by other apps written in any language.

If I write this lib in C/C++, I would have generated a .dll or .so file which can be imported and used in any other language.  How can I do this in GoLang?

If I just generate a Go executable, can I use it instead of a dynamic library?

Answer (score 6):

You can build a C-shared library in Go, this will produce a regular `.dll` or `.so` with exported functions compatible with the C calling convention, so that they can be invoked from other languages.

Compile with `go build -buildmode=c-shared`.

See `go build` command - [Build modes](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_modes)

**For example:**

**`src/go/main.go`:**

```golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export helloLib
func helloLib(x C.int) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello from Go! x=%d\n", x)
}

func main() {}
```

**`src/c/main.c`**:

```c
void helloLib(int);

int main() {
    helloLib(12345);
}
```

**Building and running**:

```
$ go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libmy.so ./src/go/
$ gcc -o test src/c/main.c libmy.so
$ ./test
Hello from Go! x=12345
$
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is possible using cgo:
https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo

It is stated that Go functions can be exported for use by C code.